# NullPointerException when creating JSON object on elasticsearch framework

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, utf-8, jackson

I'm trying to use elasticsearch, and one of the steps is to create json object to represent the index' structure. While writing this code I stumbled on a peculiar NullPointerException. The peculiar thing is that it doesn't seem deterministic. Another peculiar thing is that I found that if I rename my object's name the problems goes away (and come back some time later). It's like the memory is corrupted or something, and the objects are not freed.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._writeBytes(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1102)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeRaw(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:568)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter.writeRootValueSeparator(DefaultPrettyPrinter.java:252)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._verifyPrettyValueWrite(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:994)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._verifyValueWrite(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:980)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeStartObject(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:314)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentGenerator.writeStartObject(JsonXContentGenerator.java:131)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.startObject(XContentBuilder.java:180)
```

I managed to debug to the specific line which fails (in `UTF8JsonGenerator`):

```
System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, this._outputBuffer, this._outputTail, len);
```

(this._outputBuffer is null)

In addition I found this post from 5 years ago which seems relevant but it without any relevant solution or direction: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/utf8generator-source-code/4034

Here is the original code which cause the exception:

```
   XContentBuilder xcontentBuilder = jsonBuilder()
   .startObject()
        .field("contact_id", userStore.getContactId())
        .field("record_date", userStore.getCurrentDate())
        .startArray("locations");
            for (Location location : getLocations()) {
                xcontentBuilder.startObject() //***THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE EXCEPTION***
                    .field("city", location.getCity())
                    .field("state", location.getState())
                    .field("country", location.getCountry())
               .endObject();
            }
        xcontentBuilder.endArray()
   .endObject();
```

Comment: I see an issue with the compilation here. xcontentBuilder is being referenced on the right side of assignment operator while being declared on the left side . As right side is executed before assignment, I am not sure how  would that even compile.

Comment: @rahulroc, If I understand correctly your point please take note that there is a semicolon two rows above the 2nd usage of xcontentBuilder.

Comment: sry...missed the semicolon

Comment: did you find a solution for this ? if so please share.